# Compare One Row Value with All the Other Values in a Same Column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of single columns of single values or multiple values.

I need to compare one row value with all the other values, if one row value equals or exists in another row value in SQL.

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: Some example  data and a sample of the expected output would go a long ways to illustrating the specification. What do you want returned if a value is unique, and doesn't exist in any other row? What do you want returned when the same value exists in multiple rows?

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean by "single values or multiple values"? Are you talking about a comm-separated list? That's generally poor database design, you should normalize the data.

Answer (score 0):

You will have in second column all duplicates of value in the first column

```
select A.value, B.value
from your_table A
cross join your_table B
where A.value = B.value
order by A.value;
```

Comment: This makes my head hurt, asking *why* would we want to run this query? Yes, this query returns a second column. It excludes rows that have NULL in `value` column.  Distinct values of `value` will get returned as a single row. When there are two rows with the same value, this returns four rows with that value. When there are three rows with the same value, this will return nine rows. *Why?*

Answer (score 0):

This will return a distinct list of values found in column `myval`, along with a count of how many rows that value appears in. A count of 1 means the value appears on only one row.

```
SELECT t.myval
     , COUNT(1)  AS cnt
  FROM mytable t 
 GROUP BY t.myval
```

We could include conditions to filter out unique values, and return only duplicated values, by adding this line at the end of the query:

```
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Absent an actual specification, including example data and expected output, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I think by the description of your question is that you want to find the intersection beetwen the table within the same values of the table, 
for Exmple if you have

---tableName---
abc
dc
ab
abc

You try to get the abc and how many intersection have, that will tell you if there are any findings of not, so for that the query is simplest as this:

```
SELECT
    name, COUNT(*) as intersections
FROM
    tbl
GROUP BY
    name
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

and the result would look like this:

Hope this helps! have a great day.